# Selenium IDE Verify Text of label

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

How can I verify text of label

For example, if label 3 = 15.001 so, how can I verify this value using "Selenium IDE" command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use assertText command

Syntax: `assertText` `"<locatorForLabel3>"` `"<15.001>"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use verifyText, & verifyTextPresent, & assertTextPreset etc

[image]

In above code in Target give the locator like(i.e. xpath) and in value put 15.001

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

[This is the right answer to my question "AssertText" when we have to check value of label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaMgh.png)